# C++ error C2676: binary '==': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator

Tags: c++, list, visual-c++, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile my code for a student grading app, this is the exact error I keep getting.  Visual Studio 2019 C++ console app.

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\list(1603,65):error C2676: binary '==': 'const _Ty' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operatorwith[_Ty=Assignment]1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.27.29110\include\list(1602): message : while compiling class template member function 'auto std::list<Assignment,std::allocator<Assignment>>::remove(const _Ty &)'with[_Ty=Assignment]

The error is somewhere inside this part of the code, and I believe somewhere in removing from the list.  But I am not exactly sure where, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;


class Assignment {
public:
    std::string clas;
    std::string type;
    double grade;


    Assignment(std::string c, std::string t, double g) {
        clas = c;
        type = t;
        grade = g;
    }


    double getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }
    string getType() {
        return type;
    }
    //Check to see if user input is valid
    bool isGradeValid() {
        if (0 > grade || grade > 100)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
};


class Student {
private:
    std::string name;
    double HW_grade;
    double Test_grade;
    double overallgrade;
    std::string lettergrade;

public:
  
    list<Assignment> allAssignments;
    list<Assignment>::iterator it = allAssignments.begin();

    void editAssignment() {
        print(allAssignments);
        std::cout << "You are editng an assingment. ";
        std::string clas;
        std::cout << "Enter class: ";
        std::cin >> clas;
        std::string type;
        std::cout << "Enter type (HW or test): ";
        std::cin >> type;
        double grade;
        std::cout << "Enter grade (0-100): ";
        std::cin >> grade;
        Assignment editAssignment = Assignment(clas, type, grade);
        it = std::find(allAssignments.begin(), allAssignments.end(), editAssignment);
        if (it != allAssignments.end())
        {
            std::cout << "This is the new edited assignment. ";
            std::string clas;
            std::cout << "Enter class: ";
            std::cin >> clas;
            std::string type;
            std::cout << "Enter type (HW or test): ";
            std::cin >> type;
            double grade;
            std::cout << "Enter grade (0-100): ";
            std::cin >> grade;
            Assignment newAssignment = Assignment(clas, type, grade);
            if (editAssignment.isGradeValid() == false)
            {
                std::cout << "Assignment is not valid.\n";
            }
            allAssignments.insert(it, newAssignment);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "That assignment does not exist.\n";
            return;
        }
        
    }


    void deleteAssignment(){
        print(allAssignments);
        std::cout << "You are deleting an assingment. ";
        std::string clas;
        std::cout << "Enter class: ";
        std::cin >> clas;
        std::string type;
        std::cout << "Enter type (HW or test): ";
        std::cin >> type;
        double grade;
        std::cout << "Enter grade (0-100): ";
        std::cin >> grade;
        Assignment delAssignment = Assignment(clas, type, grade);
        it = std::find(allAssignments.begin(), allAssignments.end(), delAssignment);
        if (it != allAssignments.end())
        {
            allAssignments.remove(delAssignment);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "That assignment does not exist.\n";
            return;
        }
    }

    void setName(string n) {
        name = n;
    }
    string getName() {
        return name;
    }
    void setHWGrade(double hw) {
        HW_grade = hw;
    }
    double getHWGrade() {
        return HW_grade;
    }
    void setTestGrade(double t) {
        Test_grade = t;
    }
    double getTestGrade() {
        return Test_grade;
    }
    void setOverallGrade(double o) {
        overallgrade = o;
    }
    double getOverallGrade() {
        return overallgrade;
    }
    void setLetterGrade(string LG) {
        lettergrade = LG;
    }
    string getLetterGrade() {
        return lettergrade;
    }

    void print(std::list<Assignment> const& list)
    {
        std::copy(list.begin(),
            list.end(),
            std::ostream_iterator<Assignment>(std::cout, "\n"));
    }
};
```

Comment: I assume that's on this line? `it = std::find(allAssignments.begin(), allAssignments.end(), delAssignment);` `Assignment` doesn't have an `operator==`. You may have some trouble with that since comparing doubles for exact equality is problematic. You also need an `operator<<` that accepts an `Assignment`.

Comment: So I should create an operator overload for operator== in Assingment? @RetiredNinja

Comment: Yes, `bool operator==(const Assignment& rhs) const { ... }`